# Search error on databinding

Tags: c#, sql, database, data-binding

I'm trying to do [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2SedMeLQo4) example. [Here](http://textuploader.com/d13en) is the code i wrote. Insert/delete functions work just fine but i get error when i tried to search. Here is the search query from the code.

```
phoneBooksBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("PhoneNumber = '{0}'  OR FullName LIKE '*{1}*' OR Email='{2}' OR Adress LIKE '*{3}*'", txtPhoneNumber.Text, txtFullName.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtAdress.Text);
```

I tried to use `%` instead of `*`. Didnt work.

Comment: Your question is lacking some serious details. Why not add information about what error you are getting and some code here for reference.

Answer (score 0):

In linked source code you have extra space in second format item: you used `"{ 1}"` but it should be `"{1}"`. This should throw `System.FormatException`.